# My Ubuntu 22.04 OS wont update with "sudo apt update"

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, repository

I am new to Linux and am looking for some guidance. After trying to update my system I get two types of errors from the terminal:

1. Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu jammy Release
   404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]

2.Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::28 80]

With error type number 2 including packages from updates, backports and security.

the following explanation is given:

E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

As well as:

E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I find this strange as both of these repositories should contain the Release files needed to complete the update. I don't understand the problem. I would appriciate any help I can get.

Comment: No, actually neither should. About #2: `jammy` = 22.04, i.e., the current release. Why did you change to "old-releases"? There's no such thing for any currently support release for obvious reasons. About #1: The PPA hasn't been updated since 2021 so it can't have any content for Ubuntu 22-04. When you're "new to Linux" this are precisely the errors you should avoid.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is currently no 22.04 (Jammy) release for the PPA https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu

   - Disable that PPA
   - The system does not update PPA releases. A human made this mistake. Next time, check that you still want the PPA, and that the PPA exists for that release.
2. There is currently no 22.04 (Jammy) release for  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy

   - http://old-releases.ubuntu.com is not an active mirror for currently-supported releases. Use an active mirror instead.
   - The system does not change mirrors to old-releases. A human made this mistake.

Comment: How do I "disable that ppa"?